# asp.net:How to pass the same data between Controller and View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to identify whether it's the same client, so in Controller's action method I   put an id into the view model which will be sent to view later. When a user inputs some content in browser and submit, the view model containing user's input and the id which the controller sent to view should be sent back to controller. However, in this case, when debugging, I found the view model sent back to controller didn't carry with id. What thing did I miss?

I guess maybe View creates a new view model to loading user's input, however the id is in the old view model.

```
@model MicroCommunity.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr/>
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Department, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Department, new {@class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmployeeCardURL, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeCardURL, new {@class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Below is part of the code in GET method:

```
    // GET: /Account/Register
            var registerViewModel = new RegisterViewModel() {OpenId = wechatUserAccessToken.openid};
            return View(registerViewModel);
```

Here the POST:

```
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Openid  =model.OpenId,
                    UserName = model.OpenId,
                    EmployeeCardURL = model.EmployeeCardURL,
                    Department = new Department() {Name = model.Department},
                    Name = model.Name
                };
                try
                {
                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.OpenId);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                        // Send an email with this link
                        // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                        // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                        // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    throw;
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Post relevant code from the view and the action method

Comment: Make sure you are using the same instance of the objects.

Comment: please share you html file

Comment: To make sure that id goes back to the controller you need to render tha id in the view in an input control. Since in this case id is not necessary to be visible, you can create hidden control by using @htm.HiddenFor (m=>m.Id). This creates a model bound control and its value will go to server when you submit the form.

Comment: @guo the problem is your ID is not binded back to your model. Meaning it is not guaranteed to get the data back in controller when you pass it in the view. For it to work, create a control in your view that represents that ID, a hidden field will do if the ID is not a big factor in your UI. In this case, it will be automatically binded to your model. Of course your view should be strongly typed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no corresponding `input` field for your `OpenId` property in the view, so you cannot possibly expect it to somehow automagically be sent to your POST action. So you may consider including it as a hidden field somewhere **inside** your `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OpenId)
```

ASP.NET MVC is stateless. This means that you send one view model when rendering the view but this doesn't guarantee that you will get this same view model when you post back to another controller action.

Now, this being said, you should be aware that by using this approach, anyone can send a request to your POST controller action and *fake* the `OpenId` property with whatever value he wants. If you want to ensure that this value hasn't been tampered in between, you may consider retrieving it inside your POST action from the same place you did in your GET action (usually a database or caching layer).

So in your POST action:

```
string openId = wechatUserAccessToken.openid;
```

It's unclear what this `wechatUserAccessToken` instance is, but if it is not available in your POST action then you might consider storing this `openid` value somewhere on your server (in a db?) so that you don't need to include it in every single request as a hidden field but rather have it associated with the currently logged in user session. This will guarantee that the value will always be available and un-tampered on the server.

Comment: Thank you to point out that `OpenId` can be faked, however I cannot retrieve `OpenId` in POST, because `OpenId` is used to identify user. If client doesn't sent its `OpenId` to server, server cannot know who it is.

Comment: No, that's not true. You have perfectly fine retrieved this value in the `GET` action. So you can simply store it somewhere on your server and associate it with the current user session. You can read more about ASP.NET FOrms Authentication to learn about user sessions.